# ssh login delayed on Debian

Tags: ssh, debian, openssh, debian-bookworm

When logging in to an up to date Debian 12 (bookworm) server via ssh (to IP address) the login is delayed by ~10 seconds after entering the password (and also when doing ssh login via key).

Here is the log (`journalctl -u ssh`) of the server:

```
Dec 08 15:30:00 axx-phon-help01 sshd[2935]: Accepted password for xxx from x.x.x.x port 42038 ssh2
Dec 08 15:30:00 axx-phon-help01 sshd[2935]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user xxx(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Dec 08 15:30:25 xxx-xxx sshd[2935]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

I have already tried disabling `sshguard` and `nftables` and restart the server.

I also solved this [problem](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1018106).

Other (Debian 12) Servers in the same subnet do not have that problem.

Comment: Maybe `systemctl mask systemd-logind && pam-auth-update` solved it - but I did not not know why other servers (LXC containers) are not affected.

Comment: That sounds like an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`pam_systemd` is trying to contact `systemd-logind` but is failing.

If you have disabled `systemd-logind` as your comment suggests, you might consider removing the `pam_systemd` PAM module too.